# Nativescript 6.5 crashes on Android

Tags: nativescript

My NS 6.5 Core app works fine on iOS and also builds without issues for Android, but when I try to install it on a device (emulator or physical), I get the following error:

```html
Installing on device emulator-5554...
Successfully installed on device with identifier 'emulator-5554'.
Application com.comapny.app is not running on device emulator-5554.
This issue may be caused by:
        * crash at startup (try `tns debug android --debug-brk` to check why it crashes)
        * different application identifier in your package.json and in your gradle files (check your identifier in `package.json` and in all *.gradle files in your App_Resources directory)
        * device is locked
        * manual closing of the application
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Application com.comapny.app is not running.
```

As suggested in the error message, I checked:

- The device is not locked
- The application id is the correct one
- I tried **tns debug android --debug-brk**.  I got the same error with no additional information.

The same happens if I run **tns run android** or **tns debug android**.  I also tried it on Windows and on a Mac.

Here is my package.json:

```html
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.company.app",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.5.4"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.5.3"
    }
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/theme": "^2.3.3",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/node": "14.0.23",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "nativescript-email": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-fingerprint-auth": "^7.0.2",
    "nativescript-image-zoom": "^3.0.3",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-local-notifications": "^4.2.1",
    "nativescript-masked-text-field": "^4.0.3",
    "nativescript-numeric-keyboard": "^4.3.1",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^2.4.3",
    "nativescript-phone": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.6.3",
    "nativescript-sentry": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "^6.1.0",
    "nativescript-webview-utils": "^4.0.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "6.5.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.5.1",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "6.5.15",
    "typescript": "3.9.7"
  },
  "gitHead": "",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

What else can I try?  I am out of ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing it turned out that nativescript-sentry was the culprit.  The plugin works great on iOS, not sure what the issue is on Android.  I will be following up with the plugin author for more information.

Comment: i'm getting the error with a fresh application template, and this plugin isn't one of them. did you ever solved it ?

Comment: @Rick In my case was this plugin, but since you are not using it, I would suggest to check your other plugins.  Maybe a different one is causing the same issue

Comment: I've eventually figured it out, my mobile phone run out of disk space, i've deleted files and it run successfully ...